# Why there is two r files under r directory in android studio?

Tags: android

I am beginner in Android app development.I have a doubt in R files.I can see two r files under r directory in android studio.What is the significance of both files.I believe one R file under my specific project folder is to display the layout.What is the need of the other one. Please help me to clear this query.
[image]

Comment: There can be several _R_ files generated. One is to keep tabs of your project resources. And others may be created to keep tabs of your library resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one under `android.support.v7.appcompat` hold "resources" (I am using this word very very loosely) for appCompatv7. This is important because in the future, you may find yourself needing to make your app compatible for older versions, hence, an "appCompat"ibility resource is needed.

The one under `com.example.apzalbahin.basiccheck` is where the IDs of your views (TextViews, EditTexts, etc) are filed in.

Normally, you ***don't touch*** the R files since they would cause major problems for your application. This was a common mistake back when Android Studio wasn't out yet and Eclipse had to be used -- people accidentally modifying or deleting the R.java file.

Just leave it all on it's own and you won't have problems.

Comment: So while running the app both files are called or only the R file under com.example.apzalbahin.basiccheck ??

Comment: I'd say both files are called. They're "built in classes" (again, very loosely used) that Android needs in order to compile and run your application to a device. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two configuration mode: `Debug` and `Release` ... so two `R.java` files.. however both have the same codes i guess.

Comment: They are both under `Debug` directory